# Remove shared Google Calendar event without deleting from sharer

Tags: google-calendar

I share a Google Calendar with another person. Sometimes they enter an event that I'm not interested in. What can I do so that I don't see that event, but without deleting it so that the other person doesn't see it any more?

Comment: Apart from asking them to copy it to just their calendar?

Comment: Apart from that.